# Energy paradox in fluid mechanics

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, fluid-statics

In a fluid, the specific mechanical energy $$e_{mech}=  \frac{P}{\rho} + \frac{v^2}{2} + gz$$. Where $P$ is the static pressure, $\rho$ is the density, $v$ is the velocity, $g$ is the gravitational acceleration and $z$ is the height over some chosen reference.

Consider a cylinder filled with an incompressible fluid, with a movable piston in one end. If you apply a force at the piston, the static pressure will increase, and by the above equation, $e_{mech}$ will increase for the enclosed fluid. However, since the fluid is incompressible, the force will not work over any displacement, and will therefore not do any work on the fluid. It is just a static force.

So my question is: How can a static force that does not do any work increase the fluids energy?

I understand, of course, that this is not an actual paradox, but I would like for someone to point out where my logic is flawed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An incompressible liquid is never completely incompressible, more like *quasi-incompressible*.

So when you apply considerable force $F$ on the piston, pressure will wise by say $\Delta p$::

$$\Delta p=\frac{F}{A},$$

where $A$ is the cross-section of the piston (and assuming constant $F$).

But the liquid will have decreased slightly in volume by $\Delta V (\approx 0)$. Although small, if measured the work $W$ done by the force will still correspond to:

$$W=\int_0^{\Delta V}p(V)dV,$$

or expressed in piston displacement $h$ and force $F$:

$$W=\int_0^hF(h)dh.$$

See for example [the pV diagram of water](https://www.ohio.edu/mechanical/thermo/Intro/Chapt.1_6/pure_fluid/ex2.2_Pv.gif): the isotherms to the left are for the liquidus phase. They have a high slope but not completely vertical either, representing the limited but very real compressibility of water.

And [this table](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/bulk-modulus-elasticity-d_585.html) lists the bulk elastic moduli of a few common liquids: they're high but *infinitely* high. For instance for acetone, we have approx. $E=1 \times 10^9\:\mathrm{Pa}$ and the definition of $E$:

$$E=-V\frac{dp}{dV}.$$

From which we can derive:

$$\large{V=V_0e^{-\frac{p-p_0}{E}}}.$$

For instance for $p=100\:\mathrm{atm}$ we get:

$$V \approx 0.99 V_0,$$

or a compression of about $1\:\%$. It's not hard to see how this small $\Delta V$ combined with high $p$ does indeed constitute significant work $W$ and thus of course also an increase in $e_{mech}$.